# start this workflow to approve publishing a major version of an item. greyed out/disabled

Tags: workflow

I have got a problem. When I creating a workflow from the browser the start this workflow to approve publishing a major version of an item is **greyed out/disabled**. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Turn on "Create major and minor (draft) versions" on document library is definitely a right way to go.

**Scenario 1 - Missing value in InitiationType Element**
Make sure in your workflow definition (workflow.xml) you have included `OnMajorCheckIn` in `<InitiationType>`. For example

```
<MetaData>

    <InitiationType>Manual;#OnNewItem;#OnItemUpdate;#OnMajorCheckIn

    </InitiationType>

</MetaData>
```

MSDN - "If you do not specify an InitiationType element, Windows SharePoint Services treats the workflow as if the Manual, OnNewItem, and OnItemUpdate values have been specified"

**Scenario 2 - The option is enable to you, but you can't select it.**
Since "major and minor versions" only supported in Document Library. "Start this workflow to approve publishing a major version of an item" option was never meant to work with List. So make sure you only associate your custom workflow to Document Library if you want it to work. If you do it via code, make sure this is how you do it:

```
SPList _list = _spweb.Lists["Documents"]; 
SPDocumentLibrary docslib = (SPDocumentLibrary)(_list) 
//Add workflow to document lib not list 
docslib.AddWorkflowAssociation(yourWorkflow);
```

[Why "Start this workflow to approve publishing a major version of an item" option is disabled for my custom workflow in SharePoint?](http://www.jamestsai.net/Blog/post/Why-Start-this-workflow-to-approve-publishing-a-major-version-of-an-item-option-is-disabled-for-my-custom-workflow-in-SharePoint.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for replay, but how to add field to have got for all list templates, and all Library. What should I change to have got in all list and library this options ?

Comment: did you Turn on "Create major and minor (draft) versions" on document library?

Comment: Yes but in the Custom list it there no this option. Only in document library, and I want to cnow how could i change another template in the list.

Comment: where is the workflow.xml file?

Comment: did you check the your project? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg534715.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396